# Android - How to Open PWA external links in the default browser, not in the same app?

Tags: android, browser, progressive-web-apps, pwabuilder

I have built a PWA and works fine. I even created its APK using [PWA Builder](https://www.pwabuilder.com/) and deployed it to the Play Store. However, I noticed that all *external links* are open in the same app, and this is breaking its expected behavior because they should open in the default browser.

My external links look like this:

```
<a href="https://www.fakedomain.org" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer" />
```

And this is part of my `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "dir": "ltr",
  "lang": "da",
  "name": "My app",
  "version": "1.0.0.0",
  "scope": "/",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "start_url": "https://myapp.org",
}
```

The app is running on the root. I don't have any app folder or related. Do you have any idea how I can open the external links in the default browser and not in my app?